# Adding a custom UIButton subview in a scroll view subview's causes CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied

Tags: ios, swift

In viewDidLayoutSubView(), I am trying to add a custom uibutton to my scrollview :

```
let roundedButton = RoundedShadowButton()
roundedButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.height, 60, 60)
roundedButton.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
roundedButton.tag = 1
self.scrollView.addSubview(roundedButton)
```

I get the following error :

> 2016-01-17 18:51:23.217 momentful[61122:2267703] CUICatalog: Invalid
>   asset name supplied:  2016-01-17 18:51:23.218 momentful[61122:2267703]
>   Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with
>   identifier

Why does this happen ? How can I fix this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that you have to add it as a subview to the viewcontroller's view as well :

```
self.view.addSubview(roundedButton)
```

Everything is working as expected now.